# How secure are string values?

Tags: c++

Take the following program:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::string correct_pin = "1874";
std::string response;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter a pin.";
    std::cin >> response;

    if (response == correct_pin) {
        std::cout << "That is the correct pin!";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Incorrect pin.";
    }
}
```

Would the user be able to somehow dig into memory and find the literal `"1874"`, and reason that it must be the pin? And if so, are there any ways to make the string more secure?

Comment: `string a.out` (`a.out` is your executable) will find the `1874`. Digging into memory of running process is not needed.

Comment: You are diving into the very complex and unsolved field of software security. Yes, the data exists in memory, and if a user has sufficient rights on the system then they can eventually find and read that data. You can try obfuscating and encrypting the data, but as long as the entire solution resides on the host system, the user can in theory gain access to your secret data.

Comment: yes. You can find string literal in executable. But problem is more profound: "obscurity is not a security" so encrypting this string still is not a good solution . Basically ignore issue or prepare for long study of security. Or describe your security concerns more precisely it is possible there is some nice and simple solution.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be secure (at all). Most OSes provide some way of storing things that's at least intended to be secure, but the details vary between OSes. One route to consider would be storing the result of hashing the PIN with a  cryptographically secure hash algorithm. Doing that well isn't trivial (at all) but making it much *more* secure than your code above is pretty easy.

Comment: "Ways to make it more secure" are probably to generate a cryptographically strong 1-way hash and store _that_ in memory. The plaintext pin should only be in memory very briefly and never hard-coded. I guess you could hard-code the hash if you really need to.

Comment: "Securing the PIN" is the wrong objective. What exactly does it protect? What is your attack model? You can do all kinds of fancy stuff, but if the end user can simply patch your binary (even on-the-fly) to remove the `if` statement, it does not matter at all.

Comment: Unrelated: it takes about a second to run the program 10000 times and try every pin from 0000 to 9999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `1874` would be stored in memory and in the executable.

You could use a cryptography library to salt and hash the correct pin and store the salt and hashed value. In the past I have used crypto++. This would be almost impossible to try and figure out the original value by working with the hashed value, they would have to brute force it. Although the rest of your executable is not secure so they could just hack out the comparison of the response and the correct pin.

Comment: Makes sense. How could I make the comparison secure, in that case? Well, if there is any way.

Answer (score 1):

> Would the user be able to somehow dig into memory and find the literal "1874"

Yes. Easily.

> and reason that it must be the pin?

Not quite as easy in general, but possibly. If debug info is included, then it would be easy still. Or they could make an assumption that one of the strings is the PIN and simply all of them until they find a match.

If you just take a look at the contents of the executable, you may find something like this:

```
Enter a pin.1874That is the correct pin!Incorrect pin.;
```

What would you guess?

> And if so, are there any ways to make the string more secure?

There are ways to obfuscate, but no way to secure if you want to keep the program self contained. One potential solution is for the program to connect to your server which contains the secret, and apply zero knowledge proof techniques to use the secret.

Comment: Your "P.S. You cannot have `constexpr std::string` is not entirely accurate. C++20 changed most container constructors to be `constexpr`, and there was a proposal that _I believe_ made it in to C++20 to allow for `new` and `delete` to operate on static memory when in a `constexpr` context. Of course, this would only work for if OP is using C++20